# 2D transformation of embedded elements such as youtube

Tags: css, html

I'm looking into using CSS to transform a YouTube video on my site.

I'm aware this is possible as I've began to do so in jsFiddle, but will this slow down page speeds, or what hindrances may occur because of this, if any?

My example using...

```
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(2deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/Vh6C7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first the transformations you are doing are 2D not 3D, I've submitted an edit that fixes this in your title.

As for your question, any transformations will obviously slow down the load speed of your page, but 2D transformations are not as intensive as 3D. However, 3D transformations will actually use the GPU(some people will write a non-consequential 3D transform in order to force the GPU to render, resulting in faster speeds) to render, so if you end up doing a lot of tranformations, switch to using 3D transforms.

NEVER use `web-filter`s (blurs, sepia, b/w, contrast, etc) on your videos or embedded content, those will definitely slow down load speed as well as become extremely buggy and glitchy looking. `web-filter`s do not work well with videos.

While your example only has one YouTube video, I'm assuming that you want to put multiple on the same page arranged in a cool way. I would not recommend loading more than 3 or 4, as loading multiple embedded YouTube videos can be way more taxing on your load time than the transformations themselves. I would link to each individual video through a preview image if you are able to.